# How can I detect if a user has changed the iPhone system language settings while the app is running?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am going to use these language changes as triggers in the code that I'm going to write.

For example:

```
if languageHasChanged() {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The system posts a notification (`currentLocaleDidChangeNotification`) on locale changes. You can find more in the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1418141-currentlocaledidchangenotificati

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Register for the `NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification` notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(localeChanged), name: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func localeChanged() {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification` is not available, you can store the actual Locale in `applicationWillTerminate` and `applicationWillEnterBackground` in a variable, and compare it to the locale in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.